# Why is this PHP script showing ' Webpage Not Available '

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unsure as to why the following short PHP script is displaying 'Webpage Not Available' in Chrome when I access the page using my XAMPP server. I have error_reporting set to `= E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED` - however I'm not getting any errors generated.

I've never encountered this issue before where the page will not load without at least showing some errors...

Please see my code below:

**PHP and MYSQL**

```
$sql = "SELECT * from product WHERE brand_id NOT IN ('53', '10', '45', '29', '249')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

// load all stock
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{

// Contents of WHILE LOOP

// Size array to loop through when checking quantity
    $con_size = array (35,355,36,365,37,375,38,385,39,395,40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);
    $arrayLength_uk=count($con_size);

        for($x=0;$x<$arrayLength_uk;$x++)
        {

        // check if size is available
        if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'] > 0 )
        {

            $quantity = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_con_b'];

            $sql = "UPDATE product
            SET quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x] = $quantity,
            quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_b = 0
            WHERE quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_b > 0";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if ($result) 
            { 
               echo "Stock Updated"; 
            }
            else 
            { 
               echo "Something went wrong"; 
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Can anybody advise? Thanks.

**SOLVED**

I solved the issue - it seemed to be a problem with this `while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )` - which I changed to `mysql_fetch_array` instead.

**NEW CODE**

```
$sql = "SELECT * from product WHERE brand_id NOT IN ('53', '10', '45', '29', '249') AND active='on'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

// load all stock
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    /*
     *  Continental Sizes
     * 
     */


    //Possible size array to loop through when checking quantity
    $con_size = array (35,355,36,365,37,375,38,385,39,395,40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);
    $arrayLength_uk=count($con_size);

        for($x=0;$x<$arrayLength_uk;$x++)
        {

    // check if size is available
    if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_chain'] > 0 )
    {

        $quantity = $line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_chain'];
        $product_id = $line ['product_id'];

        echo $quantity; 

        $data = "UPDATE product
        SET quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_c = $quantity,
        quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_chain = 0
        WHERE product_id = '$product_id'";

        $result2 = mysql_query($data);

        if ($result2)
        {
            echo 'Stock Updated <br />';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Something went wrong <br />';
        }

        }
    }         
}
```

Thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: sounds like a problem with apache configuration, not with your php script. If you put a normal html file in your http root, can you access it?\

Comment: Reopen your XAMPP, this will probably help.

Comment: @giorgio - see my EDIT above. All other pages on the server are functioning fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about this line `$sql = "UPDATE product SET quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x] = $quantity, quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_b = 0 WHERE quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]_con_b > 0"`. I think `quantity_c_size_$con_size[$x]` should be `quantity_c_size_{$con_size[$x]}` and so on. I'm not sure of the right syntax, though.

Comment: yes, query looks strange. I have never seeen fields containing [$x] as part of their name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that line:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

You change `$result` variable in inner loop that is used to calculate iterations in outer loop

You should probably change:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

            if ($result) 
            {
```

into

```
$result2 = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($result2) 
        {
```

Comment: good observation but i dont think this will give "Webpage Not Available" error.

Comment: @andrew if you make that your script runs very long time browser will display info that site is unavailable even if the script itself is working correctly. So in this case I think it can cause similar problem

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the same 'Webpage Not Available' message is received. The page appears to be loading and then times-out after 20 seconds and displays 'Webpage not available'

Comment: @aphextwix Have you tried to remove the whole content that you put here in question and check if `Webpage not available` message still is displayed?

Comment: @aphextwix And what's the result after check with removed code?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - that's the whole content of the page. I'm transferring some stock values through a PHP script. If I were to take out the posted content, there would be no page.

Comment: @aphextwix I understand, but this file is probably included by some other file - you don't have here DB connection and so on, so you should make sure if you leave this file blank, there won't be an issue. Then you can put the whole code, and remove for example database update statement and make sure the issue appears (or not)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek i think more common is a message about script timeout or server time out than a "webpage not found". I guess this has to do with server config of default messages? Also, "webpage not found" is more common in WebServices requests (debug the target url), but can't be sure with the code provided.